# Proof existence of minimum and maximum on discontinuous function

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the function $g(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-x}\cdot\sin(\frac{1}{x}), &x>0 \;\\ 0, & x=0 \end{cases}$ and I have to determine if the function has a min/max in the interval $[0,1]$. I can't use the EVT because the function isn't continuous. How would you do this?

Comment: Something is not right. Is your function only defined on rationals?

Comment: You don't have a minimum or a maximum, but you have an infimum and supremum. You can get infinitely close to $\pm 1$, without reaching those values

Comment: @AnuragA sry, typo. I corrected it!

Comment: @Andrei I don't think so... The function has a minimum and maximum in my oppinion. And otherwise: how would you proof this?

Answer (score 1):

The function has values between $\pm 1$. So the maximum, if exists, it has to be at most $+1$. But the sine function varies between $-1$ and $1$, and the exponential is **strictly** less than $1$, so the maximum **must** be smaller than $1$. If you choose any $\epsilon>0$, and want to show that the maximum is $1-\epsilon$, you get a contradiction (I can get a value greater than the maximum, no matter what positive $\epsilon$ you choose). To show this, the exponential term is greater than $1-\epsilon$ if $x<\ln \frac1{1-\epsilon}$. There  are an infinite number of $x$ values between $0$ and $\ln \frac1{1-\epsilon}$ such that $1/x$ is of the form $2k\pi+\pi/2$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$. At those values the exponential part is greater that $1-\epsilon$ and the sine part is equal to $1$. Therefore the function is greater than $1-\epsilon$. So $1-\epsilon$ **is not** a maximum.